# Расположенного или расположенной

Tags: грамматика

Настоящим письмом обращаемся к вам с проьбой рассмотреть возможности установки компьютера на территории войсковой части,РАСПОЛОЖЕННОГО ИЛИ РАСПОЛОЖЕННОЙ, по адресу

Comment: У вас, простите, часть "расположена по адресу" или компьютер? Отсюда и рассуждайте.

Comment: Настоящим письмом обращаемся к вам с просьбой рассмотреть возможности установки оборудования на территории ______________,расположена по адресу , вот так?

Answer (score 1):

> Настоящим письмом обращаемся к вам с просьбой рассмотреть возможности
>   установки оборудования на территории ______________,расположена по
>   адресу , вот так?

Вы не поняли. Я не предлагал вам менять фразу. Просто хотел понять причину ваших неожиданных затруднений c падежами. Ну коль они действительно имеют место, отвечу подробно.

Здесь наиболее осмысленный вариант ***"...рассмотреть возможность установки компьютера на территории войсковой части, расположенной по адресу _____"***.

Он подразумевает, что **часть** расположена, то есть в соответствующем падеже - "[на территории] части (какой?) - расположенной по адресу".

Если вы допускаете вариант "расположенного" (*установки компьютера на территории..., расположенного по адресу*), то вы, вероятно, имеете в виду компьютер, который по этому адресу расположен, но который предназначается для установки в часть. Этот вариант представляется неактуальным, более того - несколько абсурдным, но формально возможным. Поэтому я и задал свой уточняющий вопрос.

Дополнительно.
Если адресат (получатель) письма один и это конкретное лицо, то уместнее писать ***"к Вам"*** с заглавной. Но это вы уж сами решайте, к кому обращаетесь.
И обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на запятые и единственное число слова "возможность"; - "возможности" здесь не по контексту.

Мой вариант.
***Настоящим письмом обращаемся к Вам с просьбой рассмотреть возможность установки компьютера на территории войсковой части, расположенной по адресу_________***

Comment: Спасибо за ответ